# Gets the correct response but MySQL database does not update, with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a simple registration form. I have a file for connecting to database

conn.php

```
<?php
 $db_name = "bp_reader";
 $mysql_username = "root";
 $mysql_password = "";
 $server_name = "localhost";
 $conn = mysqli_connect ($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);

/*the connection here is fine*/
if($conn){ echo "connected"; }else{ echo "not connected"; }

?>
```

the registration php

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$height = $_POST["height"];
$weight = $_POST["weight"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

//check if user exists
$sql = "select * from user_profile where user_email like '".$email."';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$response = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    $code = "registration failed";
    $message = "User already exists";


    array_push($response, array("code"=>$code, "message"=>$message));

    echo json_encode($response);

}else {
    $sql = "insert into user_profile values ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$age."', '".$height."', '".$weight."', '".$password."');";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $code = "registration Success";
    $message = "Thank you for registration... you can login now..";

    //jason data
    array_push($response, array("code"=>$code, "message"=>$message));

    echo json_encode($response);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and i have a simple html registration form

```
<html>

<body>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="email" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DOB:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" name="age" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>height:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="height" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>weight:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="weight" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I fill the form and submit, I get the correct response that the registration is successful however when I check my database on phpMyAdmin, the database remain unchanged. I am not able to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Hi there. Please don't overwrite questions with answers. If you have solved it, please add a self-answer - thanks. I've reverted this post to the last good state, so it may be of benefit to future readers.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in future.. thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If you have id field as identifier and autoincrement, you should set its:

```
   $sql = "insert into user_profile values ('', '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$age."', '".$height."', '".$weight."', '".$password."');";
```